# In PHP why use @Epochtime

Tags: php, datetime, epoch, date-conversion

I came up this sample code at

http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/php

```
$epoch = 1483228800;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output = 2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

I want to understand why the @ symbol is used and why DateTime() does not convert if the input is as below

```
$dt  = new DateTime($epoch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is format recognized by parser. [More about supported formats in official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Why `@` sign? Well, let's take date `1970-01-01 00:33:37` as a timestamp - it is `2017`. Looks like current year, doesn't it? So to make sure that you are passing timestamp, instead of something ambigous, it is prefixed with `@`.